# Minimal time in the worst case to reach destination given certain delays?

Tags: algorithm

The problem I am referring to in this question is: [Traffic Light](http://codeforces.com/gym/101775/problem/C)

It is mentioned in the question that: "Formally, Mr. Ang can set the offsets for the traffic lights to OFFi so that for each traffic light, Mr. Ang can go through it in time range [OFFi + k × (Ai + Bi), OFFi + k × (Ai + Bi) + Ai) and must wait in time range [OFFi + k × (Ai + Bi) + Ai, OFFi + (k + 1) × (Ai + Bi)) for all integers k."

But I don't understand what the offsets actually mean here. If Mr. Ang is moving from his home at time 0 and offsets represent absolute time by which he can control the start of green light, so he can adjust the offsets to never wait at any traffic light, but this is not the case in the problem. Any help in understanding this is appreciated.

Comment: If I read the problem statement correctly, Mr. Ang defines the offsets once, but the time hi leaves the house is arbitrary, that is not synchronized with the state of lights.

Comment: Yes, you are correct! Thanks a lot!